# Pseudocode interpretation

Tags: python, pseudocode

How would the following pseudocode translate into Python?

```
function IntNoise(32-bit integer: x)             

    x = (x<<13) ^ x;
    return ( 1.0 - ( (x * (x * x * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 7fffffff) / 1073741824.0);    

end IntNoise function
```

I'm not sure about the following items: the `32-bit integer: x` argument in the `IntNoise` call ; the `<<`, and the `&7fffffff`.

The function is a random number generator from this webpage:  [Perlin Noise](https://web.archive.org/web/20160510013854/http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm).

Comment: FYI, python has a built in random number generator: http://docs.python.org/library/random.html

Comment: s/function/def/, s/IntNoise/int_noise/, s/32-bit integer: //, add a colon at the end of the first line, prepend 0x to 7fffffff, drop the last ("end") line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line by line, here are the changes:

1. `function IntNoise(32-bit integer: x)`

   We don't need to declare the argument type, and prefer not to use CamelCase, so line one is:

   ```
   def intnoise(x):
   ```
2. The only thing wrong with the next line is the semicolon.  Removing it, we get:

   ```
   x = (x << 13) ^ x
   ```

   x will be *shifted to the left* by 13 bits and then the result will be bitwise *exclusive-OR*-ed with the starting value of x.
3. On the next line, once again no semicolon, and the `7ffffff` needs to be prefixed with `0x`, thus:

   ```
   return ( 1.0 - ( (x * (x * x * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 0x7fffffff) / 1073741824.0)
   ```

---

Altogether, this makes:

```
def intnoise(x):
    x = (x << 13) ^ x
    return (1.0 - ((x * (x * x * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 0x7fffffff) / 1073741824.0)
```

Comment: Very interesting. If you're not familiar with bitwise operations then the pseudocode does appear rather confusing. Especially if one reads '^' as '**'. Thanks.

Comment: The semicolon is legal and doesn't change the meaning of the Python version, but it certainly isn't idiomatic either.

Answer (score 1):

The "32-bit integer" part doesn't, unless you use `numpy.int32`. Just mask the value to 32 bits when it makes sense.

The "<<" stands.

The "& 7fffffff" Needs to be converted. The "&" stands, but the hexadecimal literal needs a bit: `0x7fffffff`.

Answer (score 1):

As a learning exercise - great, but once you've understood it, just use `os.urandom(4)` for random numbers, or the functions in `random` for various pseudo-random generators.

Comment: `os.urandom()` is probably overkill since the OP was using a pretty weak LCPRNG to start with and doesn't state why he's using it (but the downvote isn't mine). Even the cited article isn't too clear on what the PRNG is doing.

Comment: Explanation of -1: Unfortunately this question has nothing to do with random numbers (despite "random number" being used incorrectly in the linked URL). Only how to deterministically produce a pseudorandom-enough number from a seed. Sourcing entropy from the OS to use as a seed is the opposite of using a user-provided seed.

Answer (score 0):

From your code what i did understand is, the function `IntNoise` takes `32-bit integer` as an input. the `<<` is left shift operator from what i know. and it shifts the number's bit for 13 times to the left. `^` is exponential. And `7fffffff` must be a number in hex format of representation. it is 8 digit number, every digit i.e. f and 7 takes 4 bits. `f` is value for `15` in hex.